# Would like a file on the local drive, however its always created in project folder

Tags: c++, file-io

I would like a file to be created on the C:\ drive.

However my file is always created within the project folder.

my code is here:

```
myfile.open("example.txt", ios::app);
myfile << sMsg;
myfile.close();
```

I want a relative path also, however when i spell out the full path it still does not create on the local drive what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that in C++ the "\" character, as in "C:\" is an escape char so "C:\temp\somefile" translates to "C:"+ "\t" + "emp" +"\s" + "omefile" being \t the tab char and \s space.

You should write "C:\\temp\\somefile" to get the expected results (or "C:/temp/somefile")

Answer (score 3):

If you have a relative path, it will be resolved against the program's current working directory. Most IDEs set that to the project folder for the programs they launch. If you want the file to be in some specific place, don't use a relative path.

If you want to ask what happens with an absolute path, you have to actually show the program that uses the absolute path.